# Where does this extra whitespace come from when all I'm trying to do is display 2 widgets?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a widget that should only be displaying 2 widgets in it: a chat header and a chat footer. For some reason, it is adding extra whitespace. To make it easier to see, I added a border around the intended widgets so that the unintended space is show better. Why is that extra whitespace there?

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      endDrawer: Drawer(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ScreenAddUserToGroup(groupID: widget.groupID, groupName: groupName,)),
                  );
                },
                child: Text('Add User to Group'),
              )
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 8,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: groupMembersList.length ?? 0,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        final groupMember = ModelGroupMember.fromJson(groupMembersList[index]);
                        final groupMemberUsername = groupMember.username;

                        return Text(groupMemberUsername);
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          color: Colors.white,
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
        title: Text(
          groupName,
        ),
        actions: [
        ],
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(51, 50, 49, 1.0),
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 11,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent)),
                      child: ReceivedChats(groupID: widget.groupID)
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 4,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent)),
                      child: MsgInput(groupID: widget.groupID)
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      )
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Because Expanded will fill all the blanks of Column widget. Example your Column widget, you divide Column into 2 parts, part 1 occupies 11/15 area, part 2 occupies 4/15 area ( 15 is the total flex of the 2 Expanded )

Answer (score 0):

This is because the child widget of the Expanded widget is placed in the centre of the Expanded widget. If you look carefully at the MsgInput widget you can see that it is placed at the centre of the Expanded widget (second child of the Column with flex 4). Actually you are forcing the widgets to be placed in the ratio 11:4. Like this

[image]

In the previous answer I was mentioning to align the children of each expanded to the extremes. But it did not solve your problem.

To get the result you want you can remove both the expanded widgets(with flex 11 and flex 4). You can use a replace the first `Expanded` (with flex 11) widget with a `Flexible` widget set the fit property to `fit: FlexFit.tight`  . This will make the child to take up the remaining space. Remove the second `Expanded` (with flex 4)completely, use its child as the direct child of the `Column`. The result will be like this
[image]

Here the height on second child is the height of the widget itself and height of the first / top child is the remaining height of the Column.

Comment: This doesnt work. It is pushing the MsgInput section to the bottom of the screen but there is still a whitespace between the ReceivedChats widget and the MsgInput widget.